# How to integrate OffscreenCanvas in dygraph with web worker

Tags: web-worker, dygraphs, offscreen-canvas

Pure canvas can handle with OffscreenCanvas and web worker technology.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

```js
// main.js
let worker = new Worker('worker.js');

const offscreenCanvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas').transferControlToOffscreen();

worker.postMessage({ canvas: offscreenCanvas }, [offscreenCanvas]);
```

```js
// worker.js
self.onmessage = function(event) {

  const offscreenCanvas = event.data.canvas;
  const context = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');

  context.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, offscreenCanvas.width, offscreenCanvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 50);
}
```

demo effect:

[image]

But how to integrate OffscreenCanvas in dygraph with web worker? Is it can achieve? If YES, please give a demo below.

Comment: I don't know this lib, but they seem to be doing extensive use of the DOM (e.g a lot of UI event handlers) so I doubt a port to worker will be easily done.

Comment: There was some work long ago to implement an "export as PNG" feature. It might be helpful in this context, too: https://groups.google.com/g/dygraphs-users/c/whcMjtBE7s0?pli=1